# Google Translate Tools: In IE two scroll bars appears

Tags: google-translate

http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

Anyone knows the fix or option inside tool itself, to remove second scroll bar on the right and bottom?

It's only happening in IE.

Thanks ;)

```
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'lv',
    gaTrack: true,
    autoDisplay: false,
    gaId: 'UA-11173176-2',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's your web page that's causing the scrollbars(with a CSS class of overflow:scroll) rather than the tool which appears to put an fairly innocuous drop-down wherever you ask it to

Comment: maybe i can do something via javascript to fix this issue or via css rule? i have tried to overflow container and so on as overflow:hidden, but it's no go

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
html {height: 97% !important;}
```